# Java-based Windows app on Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows-10

Actually I have a portable app on Windows, it's a folder with lot of archives and a executable, it doesn't requires installation.
How do I run it on Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried running it in wine? I'm not sure that it will work, but if it is a Windows executable, then the only way to run it is in wine.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only way to run Windows executables is using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). If you have the source code, you *may* be able to compile it for Ubuntu, but Wine is your best bet. If there is a jar file of the application in question, you can run it natively on Linux.